# Read Events from Blockchain using Infura.io instead of parity

Tags: web3js

I have a Script that is reading events from the Ethereum blockchain and want to use infura.io instead of my full parity client. Unfortunately I get the following error as soon as I change the 127.0.0.1:8545 in this code to my Infura.io Access link.

```
 var fs = require("fs");
var Web3 = require('web3');

var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));



Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
at Object.InvalidResponse (/Users/moritzhubel/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/moritzhubel/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:116:24)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/moritzhubel/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/moritzhubel/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/Users/moritzhubel/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:544:12)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/moritzhubel/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:414:24)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Infura doesn't support events. I think a solution is to use something like [provider engine](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine) which has a filter sub provider.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest web3.js version (the one that is installed with a simple `npm i web3`) the following should work:

`const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/')`

Comment: Unfortunately I get another error  node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:80
    this.provider.sendAsync(payload, function (err, result) {
                  ^

TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
    at RequestManager.sendAsync

Comment: Can you do `const web3 = new Web3();console.log(web3.version)` and see which version it gives you?

Comment: Just in case...have you tried connecting to the Infura link without your access token (so just `'https://mainnet.infura.io/'`). Maybe the problem lies within the link itself.

Comment: I get version 0.20.3 as a response; yes I tried it is not the link...

Comment: That is definitely stranger. I tried installing version 0.20.3 and running the same commands as you did and everything seemed to be running ok. Does it fail straight after running the `setProvider` command or does it fail only when you call a function on it? The only way I was really able to replicate this error was changing the RPC url.

Comment: As a last resort you might wanna try updating it to 1.0.0 beta with `npm i web3@latest` and see if that makes any difference. There seem to be a lot of discrepancies from version to version. If that doesn’t yield any results then I quite frankly have no clue as to what might be causing this. Sorry.